# SWT Browser when is executed JavaScript "successful"?

Tags: javascript, java, browser, swt, xpcom

I was wondering - when calling the `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser` method execute,

- How is the `return boolean` determined?
- When is the `javaScript` execution considered "successful"?
- In particular, what happens when I start some asynchronous function and wait for the response?
- Will the browser wait for the callback?
- Is success based on an empty call stack and no errors?

Thanks in advance!

edit:
I just checked: the browser does not wait for callbacks to be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from digging in the source code, the result will be decided by either of the following methods:

- Firefox: [`JS_EvaluateScriptForPrincipals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS_EvaluateScriptForPrincipals)

  > If the script compiles and executes successfully, *rval receives the value from the last-executed expression statement processed in the script, and JS_EvaluateScriptForPrincipals or JS_EvaluateUCScriptForPrincipals returns JS_TRUE. Otherwise it returns JS_FALSE, and the value left in *rval is undefined.
- WebKit: [`JSEvaluateScript`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/javascriptcore/1451589-jsevaluatescript)

  > The value that results from evaluating script, or NULL if an exception is thrown.

So it sounds like, if there's no error, `true` will be returned.

---

As far as the async part of your question is concerned, the `Browser` will not wait for the execution of the async task. What you can do, however, is define a `BrowserFunction` (as shown in [this example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet307.java?view=co)) and call that method from JavaScript when you're done with your async task.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick response. 
My problem here is the same "and executes successfully", which does not specify what is considered successful.
When I call a function asynchronously (e.g. via setTimeout), the script will continue running and then the call stack would be empty until the specified time expires and my callback that I passed to the setTimeout function will be executed.
My question is: will the browser wait for this callback or tell me it executed successfully once the script finished running?

Comment: @chris Just try what happens if the async task fails. My guess would be that it returns `true` because it'll return after sending off the async call, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I just checked: the browser does not wait for callbacks to be called

Comment: @chris Yeah, that's what I thought.

Comment: @chris Added a part about async feedback to the answer. Let me know if this is useful or not.